# Why do we assume we are mostly from Judah (not mostly from Benjamin)?

Tags: shevatim-12-tribes, genealogy

I assumed that Benjamin was a decimated tribe after the Concubine at Gibeah incident and decided to build a MATLAB simulator to see whether with intermarriage with Judah, Benjamin would disappear (or find an equilibrium). When I looked for a reference point from which to start that has a figure for both Judah and Benjamin, I find [Chronicles 2:14:7](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16563/jewish/Chapter-14.htm#v=7) in which Judah and Benjamin fields armies of 300K and 280K respectively against the Ethiopians.

Unless one says that Judah had a big draft dodging problem, the tribes appear to be approximately equal in size.

The only possible Biblical explanation is that when Sennacherib besieged Jerusalem, he killed or carried off the Benjaminites, but this is not written.

What is the official position on why we assume people aren't Benjaminites?

Comment: Because you are called Judah in Scripture, not Benjaminites.  That is how God divided the kingdom when he tore the kingdom from Solomon, leaving only one tribe--"Judah" that he preserved for David's sake.  And Judah, not Benjamin, was the tribe David was from.

Comment: "we assume people aren't Benjaminites" How do you know this?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I assume that the OP derives this from the fact that from Megillat Ester onward, we are referred to as יהודים. This to me seems a logical fallacy (no offence meant, Clint), since the passuk which introduces Mordechai says "איש יהודי...[יחוס]... איש ימיני", "A Jewish man… [pedigree]… a Benjaminite man."

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Even hundreds of years prior to that the Jewish language is called יהודית (Isaiah 37). I'm not sure how much there is to learn from common language in post Tanakh times anyway.

Comment: If you have a source that we are assumed to be from the tribe of Judah, that would be helpful. I always assumed we were all from the kingdom of Judah

Comment: @Sarah Radak (I Kings 11:13 and II Kings 17:18) clarifies that the tribe of Binyamin had become somewhat included with the tribe of Yehuda into a larger super-tribe (particularly as Jerusalem was in the portions of both tribes), and they were therefore considered a single tribe for the purposes of those verses. This union then solidified in the form of the Kingdom of Judah (see, for e.g., I Kings 12:21-23). Also, Levi wasn't really considered a typical tribe, as they were distributed throughout the Land (probably more concentrated in Jerusalem). Therefore, many Levites also remained w/ Yehuda.

Comment: We could be from any of the tribes, as many of the "lost" tribes returned with Hezekiah and with Josiah. However the majority are from Judah. In addition, I think of the families that came back with Ezra there were more from Judah and a lot of Kohanim which explains why there are so many of them now too.

Comment: the jews of yaman have lineage papers showing which tribe they come from. not all of them come from yahudho or leiwee or beenyonmeen

Answer (score 2):

Actually, contrary to the popular belief in the Jewish world that most Jews are from either the two tribes, it's just all not true. See [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=JLGuG9gpt-0) for a proof that we are all not just from either two tribes.